# Base64 for large files?

Tags: c#, tcp, base64

I'm working on a simple file and folder transfer program in c# using the tcp protocol.

The method I use to transfer a file is to divide it into small pieces. Each of these pieces will be encoded in Base64 and inserted into a more complex JSON message which will then be sent to the other side. So every message will always be in text form thanks to Base64.

I don't have much experience with networks and I decided to make this choice because reading on the internet, sending a stream of bytes without any coding could risk that some part of the message could be interpreted by the router or firewall as a command risking interrupt the connection.

My problem is that my software also works with very large files (> 10GB) and the base64 encoding only increases the data size and makes the transfer very slow because the cpu works so much to encode/decode continuously.

Now I would like to know:

- Is it true that for example, sending a simple file converted only in bytes without first being encoded in any format, risks causing a problem to the router or firewall?
- Is it correct to use Base64 for large file transfers?
- Are there better alternatives?

Comment: TCP is a *general purpose protocol* for transmitting streams of *bytes* in both directions. If there were byte sequences it couldn't safely and reliably transmit, it would have failed in its design.

Comment: What type of binary data are you trying to send? Why is it so big?

Comment: TCP is reliable because the data is sent in blocks of up to 1500 bytes with a CRC in each block and if a block is not ACKNOWLEDGE it is resent automatically.  Encoding is not necessary, but the size of the data must be know by the receive so it doesn't stop reading at wrong spot (either a terminate character not part of the data or add byte count to the beginning). JSON is http which has special characters that cannot be sent and need to be Base64.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it true that for example, sending a simple file converted only in bytes without first being encoded in any format, risks causing a problem to the router or firewall?

Not at all. It is perfectly normal to do, for example all that HTTPS communication is binary - and it works.

> Is it correct to use Base64 for large file transfers?

While one can do this it is a useless overhead if the underlying layer supports binary data.

> Are there better alternatives?

Use binary directly. Don't encode or decode anything. Don't wrap it into layers like JSON which are not actually needed for transfer.