# How to convert Base64 string to IForm file in ASP.NET Core Web API and C#?

Tags: c#, file-io, asp.net-core-webapi

I want pass a request from frontend files as Base64 string format using ASP.NET Core Web API project. After I want to convert that  Base64 string request to an `IForm` file.

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uosc.png)

I can only save if changed like that:

```
    // Demo model class
    public class CreatePost
    {
       public string Type { set;get; }
       public IFormFile MyImage { set; get; }
    }

    // controller action method 
    public async Task<IActionResult>UploadFile(string base64String)
    {
        var base64StringFile="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"
        CreatePost() createPost = new CreatePost();
        // how to convert here Base64 string to IForm file.
    }
```

Comment: What problems are you having when you try to implement this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem looks like an issue created by some other problem you are facing. I strongly advise accepting the `IFormFile` in controller directly and demand your web application or web API clients to send you files in raw format. Base64 can be a good alternative, but not for large files. Very big files will eat up your memory and processing time if you are not cautious around them. What about file extensions and file names? You'd have to add that to the model as well. Getting closer to reinventing the wheel. Why go extra lengths when you can simply have it done by framework and have the file delivered to you on a plate as `IFormFile`?

But anyway, creating a `FormFile` from a relatively small Base64 string is quite simple:

```cs
public FormFile CreateFormFileFromBase64(string base64File)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64File);

    stream.Write(bytes);
    stream.Position = 0;

    return new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, "file", "file-name");
}
```

To process larger files, use buffering of some sort or `CryptoStream` with proper transform.

Worth reading:

[Is Base64 good for large files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55574873/base64-for-large-files)

Answer (score 1):

**Newer way to create Photo Upload API in Asp.NET Core Web API**

**Method for generating MultipartFormDataContent:**

```
     private MultipartFormDataContent GenerateContent(byte[] image, string fileName)
        {
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(image);
            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                FileName = $"{fileName}",
                Name = "FormFile",
            };
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(@"image/jpeg");
            content.Add(fileContent);
            return content;
        }
```

**Convert to byte[] from base64 string:**

```
var imageContent = Convert.FromBase64String(result);
```

**Call method to generate content to be sent as IFormFile:**

```
 var content = this.GenerateContent(imageContent , "fileName");
```

**Call/Consume this API using HttpClient:**

```
httpClientObject.PostAsync(url, content);
```

**Your API in controller will look like this:**

```
[HttpPost("photo")]
    [Consumes(ContentType.MultipartFormData)]
    public Task<IActionResult> PostPhoto(
        [FromServices] IPhotoCommand command,
        [FromForm] PhotoRequest photoRequest,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
        command.ExecuteAsync(photoRequest, cancellationToken);
```

**PhotoRequest Model:**

```
public class PhotoRequest
{
    [Required]
    [FormFileContentType(ContentType.Jpg)]
    [FormFileSize(100, 2 * 1024 * 1024)] // 100 bytes to 2MB
    public IFormFile FormFile { get; set; }
}
```